# Python get only the most recent Outlook email from a conversation

Tags: python, outlook

I'm using Python 3.5 and iterating through Outlook emails searching by message subject, if a condition is met I Save the mail to desktop. I have a problem because as I iterate through mails, I end up getting all the mails in a conversation (Both original mail and all the responses RE:) when i print the subjects that met the if condition.

On the other hand, when i save them to desktop (message.SaveAs) i get only the first email in a conversation.

What i'm interested in is only the most recent mail from a conversation, because if I save that to desktop i also get all the previous responses, so no need for 30 .msg files. Is there a way to do it? Here's my code:

```
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
folder = outlook.Folders("Main")
subfolder = folder.Folders("Incoming")
inbox = subfolder.Folders("folder1")

for x in IDX:

    messages = inbox.Items
    message = messages.GetFirst()

    for _ in itertools.repeat(None, 100):
        try:
            Subject = message.subject
            if x in Subject:
                print(Subject)
                message.SaveAs(desktop + '\\' + Subject + ".msg", OlSaveAsType['olMSG'])

             message = messages.GetNext()

         except:
             message = messages.GetNext()
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, do not loop through all items in a folder - call `Items.Restrict()` passing a restriction like `" [Subject] = 'you subject' "`, then sort the returned Items collection (`Items.Sort`) on `ReceivedTime`.